# plotlyjs bar plot fails when dealing with same x label

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

In my javascript I am using plotly `<script src="{% static 'javajs/plotly-2.24.1.min.js' %}" charset="utf-8"></script>`. Say that I want to plot 3 bars as below

```
const x = ['A', 'B', 'A'];
        const y = [1, 2, 3];
        const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

        // Create trace objects for each bar
        const trace1 = {
            x: ['A'],
            y: [y[0]],
            type: 'bar',
            marker: {
                color: [colors[0]],
                offset: -0.2
            }
        };
        const trace2 = {
            x: ['B'],
            y: [y[1]],
            type: 'bar',
            marker: {
                color: [colors[1]],
                offset: 0
            }
        };
        const trace3 = {
            x: ['A'],
            y: [y[2]],
            type: 'bar',
            marker: {
                color: [colors[2]],
                offset: 0.2
            }
        };

        // Create layout object
        const layout = {
            title: 'Bar Chart with Three Bars',
            xaxis: {
                title: 'X Axis'
            },
            yaxis: {
                title: 'Y Axis'
            },
            barmode: 'overlay',
            bargap: 0.1
        };

        // Create plotly data array
        const data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];

Plotly.newPlot(element, data, layout);
```

The above code produces 2 bars in the plot one for A and B. What I want is all 3 bars where I keep the x label as 'A','B' and 'A'.